# Azure SQL Read-Scale Out

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I have a Azure SQL Database in WEST-US region and it is Geo-Replicated to EAST-US region. Is it possible to enable the read-scale out only for the Geo-replicated database. I have tremendous amount of BI load on secondary region and really want to leverage the read scale out feature only in the secondary region. All BI ETLs directly point to secondary endpoint and would like to optimize the BI workload with the read-scale out feature.

I found the official document [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-read-scale-out) . However, I didn't find it to be clear if I can enable it only for geo-replicated database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't really matter(?)  You don't have to use the local HA readable secondary even if it is enabled.  You control this with the readintent tag on your connection string.  (It is already there for premium + vcore databases and it's just a question of whether you want to enable it).  So, if you enable it for both and just use it on the geo secondary, that works just fine.

Comment: Thanks, If I understood you correctly I still needs to enable it for both.I cannot just enable it for secondary.

Comment: I don't know if anyone has really tried, to my knowledge.  (Perhaps it was tried in testing, but there is no real financial difference to you to enable it in both).  Feel free to try it out however you'd like, but there should be no pain in turning it on in both and just using the secondary if that is what works for you

Comment: Thanks, This feature is in preview, so thought to only enable in secondary to reduce the risk on availability. I can take a hit on availability of few ETLs over the production OLTP. Agree on costing but I am aiming more on availability